# compilation generated a swf without ressource bundle

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, resourcebundle

I'm working on a flex project that uses a customized resource bundle en_US.

I linked the locale folder where there is the file en_US.properties through source path in flex build path property.

But, when use the compiled SWF in the application (web java application), the bundle shown in the pageis without icons, images, labels ...

I'm using :

- Adobe flash builder 4.7
- SDK of flash player 4.5.1.21328

is there any idea how can i procced.

Answer (score 1):

i fixed this issue by adding the following Additional compiler arguments in flex buil path properties :

> -locale=en_US -source-path=locale/{locale}